# CommunicationObjectFaultedException - System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel cannot be used for communication because it is in faulted state

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception, communicationexception

Im working on an EConnect integration in C#. I working on a function that tests the GP connection string. Basically the string consists of the Dataserver name for GP and the database name. If the database name is wrong an eConnect exception is thrown and thats easy enough to catch and keep track of. When the server name is wrong the getentity function Im using to test the connection will just spin and time out. So Im using an IAsyncResult and a wait handle to test whether or not the application times out. If the application does time out I restart the service and allow the user to reenter the server name. Now the problem Im getting is after I test inputting the wrong server and everything is reset Im getting the System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException.

Here is the info I am getting from the exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.

System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.
  Source=System.ServiceModel
  StackTrace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.OnClose(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.TypedServiceChannelFactory`1.OnClose(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.OnClose(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.GP.eConnect.ServiceProxy.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.GP.eConnect.eConnectMethods.Dispose()
   at GP_Import___Sylectus.UpdateGPConnection.TestGPConnection() in C:\GP Import - Sylectus\GP Import - Sylectus\UpdateGPConnection.cs:line 265
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)
  InnerException:
```

Here is my code:

```
namespace GP_Import___Sylectus
{
    public partial class UpdateGPConnection : Form
    {
        Task task;
        AsyncCallback cb;
        public delegate string startProcessToCall();
        startProcessToCall sp2c;
        bool test = false;
        string testResult = "";            

        public UpdateGPConnection()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.txtDatasourceName.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("GPDataServer");
            this.txtDatabaseName.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("GPDatabase");                        

            cb = new AsyncCallback(startProcessCallback);
            sp2c = new startProcessToCall(TestGPConnection);
        }

        public void startProcessCallback(IAsyncResult iar)
        {
            startProcessToCall mc = (startProcessToCall)iar.AsyncState;
            //bool result = mc.EndInvoke(iar);
            //Console.WriteLine("Function value = {0}", result);
        }

        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            config.AppSettings.Settings["GPDataServer"].Value = txtDatasourceName.Text.ToUpper();
            config.AppSettings.Settings["GPDatabase"].Value = txtDatabaseName.Text.ToUpper();
            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");

            GPCongfigSettings.GPConnectionString = @"data source=" + txtDatasourceName.Text.ToUpper() + ";initial catalog=" + txtDatabaseName.Text.ToUpper() + ";integrated security=SSPI;persist security info=False;packet size=4096";

            IAsyncResult asyncResult = null;
            asyncResult = sp2c.BeginInvoke(cb, null);


            Thread.Sleep(0);

            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            test = asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(15000);

            if (test)
            {
                try
                {
                    testResult = sp2c.EndInvoke(asyncResult);
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
                }
            }

            bool result = asyncResult.IsCompleted;

            string eConnectServiceName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("eConnectServiceName");

            string eConnectProcess = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("eConnectProcess");

            Process[] process = Process.GetProcessesByName(eConnectProcess);

            if (!test)
            {                          

                foreach (Process tempProcess in process)
                {
                    tempProcess.Kill();
                }
                RestartService(eConnectServiceName, 20000);

                RestartService(eConnectServiceName, 20000);
            }

            asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.Close();


            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;                

            if (test == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Dataserver Name is Incorrect", "Connection String Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
            }
            else
            {
                if (testResult == "Correct Connection")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Connection String Successfully Updated", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                    this.Close();
                }
                else if (testResult.Contains("eConnect Exception"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Database Name is Incorrect", "Connection String Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(testResult, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    RestartService(eConnectServiceName, 20000);
                }
            }            
        }          

        public string TestGPConnection()
        {

            eConnectMethods requester = new eConnectMethods();
            try
            {                

                // Create an eConnect document type object
                eConnectType myEConnectType = new eConnectType();

                // Create a RQeConnectOutType schema object
                RQeConnectOutType myReqType = new RQeConnectOutType();

                // Create an eConnectOut XML node object
                eConnectOut myeConnectOut = new eConnectOut();

                // Populate the eConnectOut XML node elements
                myeConnectOut.ACTION = 1;
                myeConnectOut.DOCTYPE = "GL_Accounts";
                myeConnectOut.OUTPUTTYPE = 2;
                myeConnectOut.FORLIST = 1;
                myeConnectOut.WhereClause = "(ACTNUMST = '99-9999-99-999')";

                // Add the eConnectOut XML node object to the RQeConnectOutType schema object
                myReqType.eConnectOut = myeConnectOut;

                // Add the RQeConnectOutType schema object to the eConnect document object
                RQeConnectOutType[] myReqOutType = { myReqType };
                myEConnectType.RQeConnectOutType = myReqOutType;

                // Serialize the eConnect document object to a memory stream
                MemoryStream myMemStream = new MemoryStream();
                XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(myEConnectType.GetType());
                mySerializer.Serialize(myMemStream, myEConnectType);
                myMemStream.Position = 0;

                // Load the serialized eConnect document object into an XML document object
                XmlTextReader xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(myMemStream);
                XmlDocument myXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                myXmlDocument.Load(xmlreader);

                var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;
                int timeOut = 20000; //20 seconds

                try
                {
                    string reqDoc = requester.GetEntity(GPCongfigSettings.GPConnectionString, myXmlDocument.OuterXml);
                }
                catch (CommunicationObjectFaultedException cofe)
                {
                    return "Communication Exception - " + cofe.Message;
                }

                //connection string is correct
                return "Correct Connection";


            }
            catch (FaultException fe)
            {
                return "Fault Exception - " + fe.Message;
            }
            catch (eConnectException exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
                return "eConnect Exception - " + exc.Message;
            }            
            catch (CommunicationObjectFaultedException cofe)
            {
                return "Communication Exception - " + cofe.Message;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "Exception - " + ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Release the resources of the eConnectMethods object
                requester.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        public static void RestartService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
        {
            ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
            try
            {

                int millisec1 = Environment.TickCount;
                TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);

                if (!service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped))
                {
                    service.Stop();
                    service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);
                }


                // count the rest of the timeout
                int millisec2 = Environment.TickCount;
                timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds - (millisec2 - millisec1));

                if (service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped) || service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending))
                {
                    service.Start();
                    service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // ...
            }
        }          


    }

}
```

The error always seems to occur when I try to dispose the requester method in TestGPConnection.

Any ideas what I should do? Ive been googling this all day and Im getting pretty confused with what Im finding on how to fix this.

Comment: I think that you find the problem only when there is an error on communication. Can you try to use the channel with using?

Comment: not exactly sure what you mean

Comment: Which one is `line 265` in your code?

Comment: Line 265 is: 
requester.Dispose();

Comment: Then you should rather check the `eConnectMethods` class `Dispose` method. Something failing there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code:

```
        public string TestGPConnection()
        {
            try
            {                
               using (eConnectMethods requester = new eConnectMethods())
               {
                // Create an eConnect document type object
                eConnectType myEConnectType = new eConnectType();

                // Create a RQeConnectOutType schema object
                RQeConnectOutType myReqType = new RQeConnectOutType();

                // Create an eConnectOut XML node object
                eConnectOut myeConnectOut = new eConnectOut();

                // Populate the eConnectOut XML node elements
                myeConnectOut.ACTION = 1;
                myeConnectOut.DOCTYPE = "GL_Accounts";
                myeConnectOut.OUTPUTTYPE = 2;
                myeConnectOut.FORLIST = 1;
                myeConnectOut.WhereClause = "(ACTNUMST = '99-9999-99-999')";

                // Add the eConnectOut XML node object to the RQeConnectOutType schema object
                myReqType.eConnectOut = myeConnectOut;

                // Add the RQeConnectOutType schema object to the eConnect document object
                RQeConnectOutType[] myReqOutType = { myReqType };
                myEConnectType.RQeConnectOutType = myReqOutType;

                // Serialize the eConnect document object to a memory stream
                MemoryStream myMemStream = new MemoryStream();
                XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(myEConnectType.GetType());
                mySerializer.Serialize(myMemStream, myEConnectType);
                myMemStream.Position = 0;

                // Load the serialized eConnect document object into an XML document object
                XmlTextReader xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(myMemStream);
                XmlDocument myXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                myXmlDocument.Load(xmlreader);

                var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;
                int timeOut = 20000; //20 seconds

                try
                {
                    string reqDoc = requester.GetEntity(GPCongfigSettings.GPConnectionString, myXmlDocument.OuterXml);
                }
                catch (CommunicationObjectFaultedException cofe)
                {
                    return "Communication Exception - " + cofe.Message;
                }

                //connection string is correct
                return "Correct Connection";
                }
            }
            catch (FaultException fe)
            {
                return "Fault Exception - " + fe.Message;
            }
            catch (eConnectException exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
                return "eConnect Exception - " + exc.Message;
            }            
            catch (CommunicationObjectFaultedException cofe)
            {
                return "Communication Exception - " + cofe.Message;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "Exception - " + ex.Message;
            }
            //finally
            //{
            //    // Release the resources of the eConnectMethods object
            //    requester.Dispose();
            //}
        }
```

Comment: This should no way solve the issue. Cause `using` and `try .. finally` both are same? not sure how you think this would solve

Comment: This at least handles the error a little better, doesnt cause visual basic to crash my app and instead sends the exception through so I can display it in the messagebox. Another thing I noticed that once the messagebox displays with the CommunicationObjectFaultedException exception, if I close it and reenter my info it works properly